# WPF Change between 2 windows

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I have been searching everywhere for the answer to my problem but i cant seem to locate anything.

I am trying to open 2 different windows, that i have already created, after a button press. On the button press, i go to open the new window, but it just opens a blank window, not the window i want.

This is my function that i am trying to open my new window with, and it is inside my MainWindow, and i want to open my window i have created in Jobs (see image below).

```
void Jobs_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window Jobs_Window = new Window();
    App.Current.Jobs = Jobs_Window;
    Jobs_Window.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz93Q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of the standard Window class rather than your custom Window that you have made.

If you have added a Window, called JobsWindow for example, then create an instance of that rather than just the .NET built-in Window:

```
void Jobs_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window Jobs_Window = new JobsWindow();
    App.Current.Jobs = Jobs_Window;
    Jobs_Window.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```